# A way to view recent played with?

Tags: rocket-league

Is there a way to view players i recently played with except the steam overlay? I know there was a year ago in the log files but they fixed it by now. I tried to use the steam webinterface but i won´t show recent players i played in rocket league. It only shows up a list in the steam overlay. Is there a way to extract those players from a file or sth ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The overlay is the only method I'm aware of, unfortunately

Comment: Where so I find this in the overlay? I have been looking for a while but can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other way than using the steam overlay, except you can write yourself some basic scripts in like java or something like that. But if you **really** want to have those player names in a list automatically and you have some basic programming understanding, you could write yourself a script which fetches the information from this URL ([http://steamcommunity.com/id//friends/coplay/](http://steamcommunity.com/id/awusuwah/friends/coplay/)) and then save it wherever you like. (.txt file, spreadsheet etc.) To use this link, you have to be signed into steam on your browser. Maybe this can help you!